# Could not create task ':path_provider:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'. this and base files have different roots:

Tags: flutter

I've tried to sign the project with Gradle files, but I've faced these two errors, anyone can help me.

Errors:
[image]

thanks

Comment: HOw did you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me , in `pubspec.yaml` file change dependency for `path_provider` with latest one.
in my case I replaced **path_provider: ^2.0.2** with `path_provider: ^2.0.8`
you can get latest version of `path_provider` at https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider/versions

Note : if error still continues:
Open Project in as Open Android module in Android studio [as shown in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzNyv.jpg)

now got to `build.gradle` file and change

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
```

with

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
```

and build the project again.